# Merge sort is not working

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, mergesort

i'm working on merge sort, i know i got problem when one of the list goes 
empty while comparing..then it will print null values after that..
help me out to handle the conditions..i couldn't use to conditional statements properly.
Thanks in advance..:)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void merge(int *a, int n, int *b, int m)
{
    int i=0, j=0, c[100], k=0;

    //make traitment :
    //================
    while(i!=n && j!=m) {
      if(i!=n)
         c[k++] = a[i]>b[j] ? b[j++] : a[i++];
      else
        c[k++] = a[j];

      if(j!=m)
        c[k++] = a[i]>b[j] ? b[j++] : a[i++];
      else 
        c[k++] = a[i];
    }

    //view the result :
    //================
        for(i = 0;i < (n+m);i++) { 
          printf("%d\n", c[i]); 
        }
   }
void main() {
    int size,size2;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    scanf("%d", &size2);
    int ar[size], br[size2],i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
      { 
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]); 
      }
    for(i = 0; i < size2; i++)
      { 
        scanf("%d", &br[i]); 
      }
    merge(ar, size, br, size2);

  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You're sorting your data in your `merge` function (which is needlessly complex) into a local array `c[]`. which has *nothing* to do with *anything* once that function returns. The two passed in arrays remain untouched, and ultimately unsorted.

Answer (score 1):

k should not be bigger than (m+n) - 1, so change the while condition as follow :

```
  while(k <= (m+n-1))
```